# How to prevent jquery function from executing before executing the other one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have these JQuery functions:

**1st**

```
$(function(){

  //  Accordion Panels
  $(".staffDiv div").hide();

  $(".staffDiv img").hover(function(){

      // $(".staffDetails").slideUp("fast");

      $(this).next(".staffDetails").slideToggle("slow").siblings(".staffDetails:visible").slideUp("fast");
      $(this).toggleClass("current");
      $(this).siblings("div").removeClass("current");

  });
});
```

**2nd**

```
$(function(){

    $(".branchDiv").click(function(){
        var toggleWidth = $(this).width() == 450 ? "175px" : "450px";
        $(this).animate({ width: toggleWidth });
    });
});
```

How can I prevent the first one from executing if the second one is not executed yet?

---

**EDIT**
This is my new code now:

```
$(function(){
$(".staffDiv div").hide();
$(".branchDiv").click(function(){
        var toggleWidth = $(this).width() == 450 ? "175px" : "450px";
        $(this).animate({ width: toggleWidth });

        $(".staffDiv div").hide();
          $(".staffDiv img").hover(function(){
              $(this).next(".staffDetails").slideToggle("slow").siblings(".staffDetails:visible").slideUp("fast");
          });
  });
});
```

**EDIT** This is the HTML Code. Should I continue what I'm doing or drop the fancy effects and make a classic organizational chart?

```
<div class='branchDiv'> 
<div class='staffDiv'>
    <img class='staffPic' src='images/upload/1378622_10202067392155670_1672420239_n.jpg'/>
    <div class='staffDetails'>
        Name:n m n<br/>
        Position:m<br/>
        Specialization:m34<br/>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is confusing because both bodies of code are event handlers.  Those event handlers will execute their callbacks when the event occurs (hover in the first block and click in the second block).  You don't control when those events occur, that depends upon the user's actions.

Comment: @jfriend00 I edited my code based on Mr. Rob answer. Kindly take a look again.

Comment: You do not want to install a `.hover()` event handler inside your `.click()` handler.  Every time there's a click, you will install yet another `.hover()` handler and there will be multiple ones installed.  What I'd suggest you do is backup and describe what you're trying to accomplish and we can then help advise what kind of code could do that.

Comment: I am trying to code an Organizational Chart. The organizational chart has branches so initially to save space, the branches are minimized, details are hidden. The mouse click will make the branch grow and the mouse hover will show the employee details. Am I just making it hard for myself?

Comment: The `.hover()` should be outside the `.click()` for sure.  The rest is hard to advise without being able to see your HTML and understand what specific question you want help with.

Comment: 1st & 2nd pieces of code are synchronous. What the reason to wait for the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to nest the first within the second (sync you aren't doing any asynchronous actions):

```
$(function(){
  // this will dictate whether the hover event does anything
  var open = false;

  $(".branchDiv").click(function(){
     var toggleWidth = $(this).width() == 450 ? "175px" : "450px";
     $(this).animate({ width: toggleWidth });
     open = ($(this).width() > 175);
  });

  $(".staffDiv div").hide();

  $(".staffDiv img").hover(function(){
      if(open){
         $(this).next(".staffDetails").slideToggle("slow").siblings(".staffDetails:visible").slideUp("fast");
         $(this).toggleClass("current");
         $(this).siblings("div").removeClass("current");
      }
  });
});
```

If the 1st was supposed to happen within the `onclick`, move the code under your `$(this).animate` call

Comment: it worked at first, so I click the DIV then the width increase, I hover to the image some details will show..but when I click the DIV again the width decrease but i can trigger the hover without clicking after that

Comment: I've updated my example that uses a flag to control the hover event actions

Comment: still not working...the hover activates after I close the div